# android something wrong with the loop-cannot put the value into hashmap

Tags: java, android

This problem has bothered me for a long time. I use a cloud database called bmob, and I found that I can successfully get the data I want. However, there might be some mistakes in the loops, and I could only get the information of the last selected item.

p.s. I use an array list called Playlist to store the calculated data that I will use to display a list-view in the next activity.

here is my code:

```
public class DestinationActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {

private TextView from_place, date, days, start_time, end_time, number, money_view;
private Button addButton, subButton;
private ImageView backButton, telephone;
private ListView listView;
private Button destinationOk_btn;
private ShapeLoadingDialog shapeLoadingDialog;

private Tip startTip;

private Calendar calendar;
private DatePickerDialog dialog;
private TimePickerDialog dialog2;

private List<Destination> destinationList = new ArrayList<Destination>();


private DestinationAdapter adapter;

private int number_value = 1; 

private String time_start;
private String time_end;
private int travel_days;
double travelTime;//total playing time
double travel_time;
private int money;
private int num = 1;


private ArrayList<Integer> select_placeID = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
public Map<Integer,Double> weightMap;
public List<Plan> planList = new ArrayList<Plan>();
int[] selectedID = new int[10];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.destination_layout);

    //initialize the cloud database
    Bmob.initialize(this, BmobConfig.APP_ID);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_destination);

    destinationOk_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okButton);


    initDestinations(); // initialize the data


    adapter = new DestinationAdapter(destinationList, DestinationActivity.this);
    //adapter = new DestinationAdapter(this, destinationList, DestinationAdapter.getIsSelected());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //....listeners and textviews.......

    //submit button
    destinationOk_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            select_placeID.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < destinationList.size(); i++) {
                if (DestinationAdapter.getIsSelected().get(i)) {
                    select_placeID.add((i + 1));
                }

            }

            //change to int array
            selectedID = new int[select_placeID.size()];
            for(int i = 0;i<select_placeID.size();i++){
                selectedID[i] = select_placeID.get(i);
            }

            if (select_placeID.size() == 0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(DestinationActivity.this);
                builder1.setMessage("no records");
                builder1.show();
            }
            else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DestinationActivity.this);

                builder.setMessage("waiting for magic...");
                builder.show();

                /**
                 * calculate the route
                 */
                if (validate()) {
                    new calRoute().execute();
                }


            }
        }

    });
}



//initialize the data
private void initDestinations() {
    //........
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //.......
}


/**
 * asynctask
 */
private class calRoute extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Plan>>{


    public calRoute(){
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    protected List<Plan> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        List<Plan> result = calculate(time_start, time_end, travel_days);

        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Plan> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            Toast.makeText(DestinationActivity.this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if(planList.size() > 0) {


                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(DestinationActivity.this, ActivityPlan.class);

                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("planInfo", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) planList);

                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else{
                Toast.makeText(DestinationActivity.this, "no plan", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
}


/**
 *plan
 **/
public List<Plan> calculate(String time_start, String time_end, int travel_days) {


    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(("HH:mm"));

    Date starttime = new Date();
    Date endtime = new Date();
    try {
        starttime = df.parse(time_start);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        endtime = df.parse(time_end);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    double l = endtime.getTime() - starttime.getTime();
    double hour = (l / (60 * 60 * 1000));
    double min = ((l / (60 * 1000)) - hour * 60);

    if(min == 0){
        min = 60;
    }
    else {
        travel_time = ((1.0 * travel_days * hour) * (min / 60)); 
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
        travelTime = Double.parseDouble(decimalFormat.format(travel_time));
    }


    weightMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Double>(); //store weight
    int totalPriority = 0;//total priority

    final Destination start = new Destination(116.32133, 39.92269);


    final HashMap<Integer, Integer> pMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    final HashMap<Integer, String> nameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    final HashMap<Integer, Destination> objectMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Destination>();
    /**
     * get the data from cloud database
     */
            BmobQuery<Destination> query = new BmobQuery<Destination>();
            for (int sid: selectedID) {

                query.addWhereEqualTo("id", sid);


                query.findObjects(new FindListener<Destination>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(List<Destination> list, BmobException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            System.out.println("success：total" + list.size() + "items。");
                            for (Destination destination : list) {


                                int p = destination.getPriority();

                                int id = destination.getId();

                                String name = destination.getName();

                                double longitude = destination.getLongitude();
                                double latitude = destination.getLatitude();

                                objectMap.put(id, new Destination(longitude, latitude));

                                System.out.println(id);


                                double dis = DistanceUtil.distance(start.getLongitude(), start.getLatitude(),
                                        longitude, latitude);

                                pMap.put(id, p);
                                weightMap.put(id, new Double(dis));
                                nameMap.put(id, name);

                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i("bmob", "error：" + e.getMessage() + "," + e.getErrorCode());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }


    for (Integer key : pMap.keySet()) {
        int p = pMap.get(key).intValue();
        totalPriority = totalPriority + p;
    }


    double weight = 0.0;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> hm : weightMap.entrySet()) {
        double hm2Value = pMap.get(hm.getKey());
        weight = totalPriority / hm.getValue() * hm2Value;

        weightMap.put(hm.getKey(), weight);
    }


    /**
     * 按照weight值来排序
     * 判断是否传递数据给plan_activity
     */
    MapUtil.sortByValue(weightMap);

    //排好序后计算距离
    Iterator it = weightMap.entrySet().iterator();
    int order = 0;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        order++;
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        objectMap.put(new Integer(order), objectMap.get(entry.getKey()));
    }


    PlanTask planTask = new PlanTask();//封装了每个plan计算的方法


    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> entry : weightMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("id= " + entry.getKey());


        double play_time = planTask.calPlay_time(weightMap.size(),
                weightMap.get(entry.getKey()), travelTime);

        double driving_time = planTask.calDrive_time(DistanceUtil.distance(
                objectMap.get(entry.getKey()).getLatitude(),
                objectMap.get(entry.getKey()).getLongitude(),
                objectMap.get(entry.getKey() + 1).getLatitude(),
                objectMap.get(entry.getKey() + 1).getLongitude()
        ));

        String arrive_time = "hello world";//未完待续

        String place_name = nameMap.get(entry.getKey());

        Plan plan = new Plan(place_name, arrive_time, driving_time, play_time);

        //传递plan对象list
        planList.add(entry.getKey(), plan);
    }

    return planList;

}
```

}

When I debug it, I found that in calculate() functions, the output of

```
  BmobQuery<Destination> query = new BmobQuery<Destination>();
            for (int sid: selectedID) {

                query.addWhereEqualTo("id", sid);


query.findObjects(new FindListener<Destination>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(List<Destination> list, BmobException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            System.out.println("success：total" + list.size() + "items。");
                            for (Destination destination : list) {

                                int p = destination.getPriority();

                                int id = destination.getId();

                                String name = destination.getName();


                                double longitude = destination.getLongitude();
                                double latitude = destination.getLatitude();

                                objectMap.put(id, new Destination(longitude, latitude));

                                System.out.println(id);

                                //calculate the distance
                                double dis = DistanceUtil.distance(start.getLongitude(), start.getLatitude(),
                                        longitude, latitude);

                                pMap.put(id, p);
                                weightMap.put(id, new Double(dis));
                                nameMap.put(id, name);

                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.i("bmob", "error：" + e.getMessage() + "," + e.getErrorCode());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

is "success：total 1 items." and after the loop, if I have selected 3 items, it would be "success：total 1 items."  for 3 times and only the information of the last item is caught. 
AND the size of three hash map: pMap, nameMap and objectMap are all zero. Why is it??? It is so strange...

There is no error in LogCAT, however, the ordered list view cannot display in the second activity. PLEASE help me, it has bothered me for a long time.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out much unfortunately, since I am not really comfortable with reactive programming yet as the platform uses a lot of rxjava in general, but here is something that would enhance the code a little bit

```
final HashMap<Integer, Integer> pMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
final HashMap<Integer, String> nameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
final HashMap<Integer, Destination> objectMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Destination>();

/**
 * get the data from cloud database
 */
BmobQuery<Destination> query = new BmobQuery<Destination>();

// this time only one list of three elements is added instead of three lists of one element each
query.addWhereContainedIn("id", Arrays.asList(selectedID));

query.findObjects(new FindListener<Destination>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<Destination> list, BmobException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        System.out.println("success：total" + list.size() + "items。");
                        for (Destination destination : list) {

                            int p = destination.getPriority();

                            int id = destination.getId();

                            String name = destination.getName();


                            double longitude = destination.getLongitude();
                            double latitude = destination.getLatitude();

                            objectMap.put(id, new Destination(longitude, latitude));

                            System.out.println(id);

                            //calculate the distance
                            double dis = DistanceUtil.distance(start.getLongitude(), start.getLatitude(),
                                    longitude, latitude);

                            pMap.put(id, p);
                            weightMap.put(id, new Double(dis));
                            nameMap.put(id, name);

                        }
                        // continue execution here though you won't be able to return a list of plans here
                    } else {
                        Log.i("bmob", "error：" + e.getMessage() + "," + e.getErrorCode());
                    }
                }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thanks a lot for helping!! I am trying this method, but the method findObject() is written by the cloud platform. Actually I am a beginner in multithreading, and I don't know how to do this.  I am trying to add synchronized (this) { ... findObject() ......... }, but this does not work...

Comment: unfortunately, it turns out that there is no synchronous way as it is not provided by the framework. but the code needs some modifications for it to work, I will edit the answer soon

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<HashMap<Integer, Destination>> listmap=new ArrayList<>;
    final HashMap<Integer, Destination> objectMap;

    /**
     * get the data from cloud database
     */
    BmobQuery<Destination> query = new BmobQuery<Destination>();

    // this time only one list of three elements is added instead of three lists of one element each
    query.addWhereContainedIn("id", Arrays.asList(selectedID));

    query.findObjects(new FindListener<Destination>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<Destination> list, BmobException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            System.out.println("success：total" + list.size() + "items。");
                            for (Destination destination : list) {
                                objectMap = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, Destination>();
int id = destination.getId();
                                objectMap.put(id, destination);
                                listmap.add(objectMap);

                            }
                            // continue execution here though you won't be able to return a list of plans here
                        } else {
                            Log.i("bmob", "error：" + e.getMessage() + "," + e.getErrorCode());
                        }
                    }
```

Try this